# How to add string items to an enum in c#?

Tags: c#

I have used a enum type data type to add string element in a comboBox in windows form c# but a error has been ocurred while adding the elements in it.
Error is ("Identifier Expected")
My code is

```
public enum EducationG
        {
            ("Bachelor of Arts (B.A)"),
            ("Bachelor of Arts (Bachelor of Education (B.A. B.Ed)")],
            ("Bachelor of Arts (Bachelor of Law (B.A.B.L)"),
            ("Bachelor of Arts (Bachelor of Law (B.A.LLB)"),
            ("Bachelor of Ayurvedic Medicine and Surgery (B.A.M.S)"),
            ("Bachelor of Applied Sciences (B.A.S)"),
            ("Bachelor of Audiology and Speech Language Pathology (B.A.S.L.P)"),
            ("Bachelor of Architecture (B.Arch)"),
            ("Bachelor of Business Administration (B.B.A)"),
            ("Bachelor of Business Administration (Bachelor of Law (B.B.A LL.B)"),
            ("Bachelor of Business Management (B.B.M)"),
            ("Bachelor of Business Studies (B.B.S)"),
            ("Bachelor of Computer Applications (B.C.A)"),
            ("Bachelor of Communication Journalism (B.C.J)"),
            ("Bachelor of Computer Science (B.C.S)")
}
```

Comment: Enums can't contain string literals. What are you trying to do?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: i want to add the string element to the combobox of my windows form using forloop

Comment: You are using a very wrong approach! My sugession, create two static `Dictionary<EducationG, String>` and `Dictionary<String, EducationG>`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enums don't contain strings. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/sbbt4032.aspx) describes them like this:

> The enum keyword is used to declare an enumeration, a distinct type consisting of a set of named constants called the enumerator list. Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be any integral type except char. The default underlying type of the enumeration elements is int. By default, the first enumerator has the value 0, and the value of each successive enumerator is increased by 1.

Perhaps what you are looking for is a string array.

```
string[] EducationG = {
    "Bachelor of Arts (B.A)",
    "Bachelor of Arts (Bachelor of Education (B.A. B.Ed)",
    ....
}
```

If all you want to do is add a bunch of strings to a combo box, then a string array is fine. But if you really do need an enumeration then you'll want to declare an `enum` and find a way to map between the enum values and the string names. The `Description` attribute will do the trick.

Comment: i have replaces the keyword enum with string[] but it is still showing the same error

Comment: @user But I did not suggest doing that. I suggested using a `string[]` and showed the syntax for declaring one with an array initializer. Of course, I don't actually know what problem you are trying to solve. So, perhaps you don't want a string array. You need to slow down a little and try to understand your problem, and learn the language properly.

Comment: My code compiles fine. I don't know what your code looks like.

Comment: friend i have made this in external class now will you please tell me how can i call this in anther class. Please........

Comment: sorry............ u were true that does not suite my question, hey please vote my question so that i got privilege to vote up your answer :)

Comment: I'm curious, do you know @user2327043? Are you the same person? I ask because you may not realise, that operating two accounts that vote for each other, and accept each others answers will possibly lead to a site ban. I don't mind if you accept a different answer, but it ought to at the very least answer the question.

Comment: co i dont know the man who answed my question i found it usefull that's why i accept it but afterwards when it was giving alt of error i unaccepted that and accepted ur answer, dear if i am a same user why would i unaccept that anser now. tell me !

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that but you can do this:

```
public enum EducationG
{
    [Description("Bachelor of Arts (B.A)")]
    BachelorOfArtsBA,

    ...
}
```

You can convert the enum to a string using:

```
var enumValue = EducationG.BachelorOfArtsBA;
var attrs = (DescriptionAttribute[])typeof(EducationG)
    .GetField(enumValue.ToString())
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute));
var stringValue = attrs[0].Description;
```

To convert the string back to an enum is a bit more challenging:

```
var stringValue = ...
var enumValue = 
    from f in typeof(EducationG).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static)
    from d in (DescriptionAttribute[])f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute))
    where d.Description == stringValue
    select f.GetValue(null);
```

In any case, this solution is probably more complicated that your particular problem warrants.

Comment: This will work but you should also explain him that what is enum and what should be the better approach for this kind of data.

Comment: and, how to change description to enum again ?

Comment: thanks  u it is good method to but for this i will have to more coding................... but thanks thank u so much for help @p.s.w.g

Answer (score 0):

Please see the examples in the link 
[emun(C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) the code may look something like:

```
public enum EducationG {SomeName, SomeOtherName};
```

As you'll note in the link you can also add defaults and flags to the enums.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a `List<string>` which would look like this:

```
var educationGrades = new List<string> 
{ 
    "Bachelor of Arts (B.A)", 
    "Bachelor of Arts (Bachelor of Education (B.A. B.Ed)", 
    ... 
    "Bachelor of Computer Science (B.C.S)"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string and justcode like this

```
private void edulvlcb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                   combobox.Items.Clear();
            foreach (string ug in Classname.stringname)
                combobox.Items.Add(ug);
    }
```

it must work

Comment: @user2214972 Why did you change the accept from an answer that addressed the question that you asked, to this answer which is completely unrelated to the question that you asked, and does not even remotely compile? And which arrived very shortly after you unaccepted? There is no `stringname` anywhere to be seen?